# Unital subrings of fields are all domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that any subring of a field which contains the identity is an integral domain. 
Do i need to show that $ab = 0$ where $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Or in general What do you need to show in order something is an integral domain

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that, for all $a, b$ in the ring, if $a b = 0$ then either $a = 0$ or $b$.

Hint: What do the field axioms tell you about multiplication?